# For loop with condition in Python

Tags: python

I'm stuck on this problem. How can I create a program that adds 1 randomly to a list of [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]. And I wanted to keep it going until all the numbers in the list is at least > 0.

I have three problems in my code and I don't know what it is. This my code and the list Votes = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]:

1. It stops printing after the 7th time
2. Sometimes it’s starts with more than 1 in an item

I want it to start it with an just 1 in a list and from there add 1 randomly to a item in the list.

So I want at least one of each in the list which would be greater than 0.

My code is

```
Def get_all_prizes():
       For items in votes:
              Items = random.radiant(0, 5)
              Votes[items] + = 1
               If items == 0:
                    False
               Else:
                    Print(votes)
```

This is what is printed

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0]
```

It only does 6 times, and sometimes it starts like this. I wanted it to start just by having just 1 number in the list like the previously printed stuffs

```
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Please don't add images at all. Please put your code directly into the question.

Comment: Please format your code as code (use the `{}` button), and also use real code with correctly cased keywords .

Comment: Your code is totally unreadable. Please post a proper mcve (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you could use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) to check if every element is larger than 0 and keep looping with [`while`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) until this condition is fullfilled:

```
import random
n = 6
votes = [0] * n

while not all(votes):
    i = random.randrange(0, n)
    votes[i] += 1
    print(votes)

#   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
#   [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
#   [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
#   [1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0]
#   [1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1]
#   [1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1]
#   [1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1]
#   [1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1]
#   [2, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1]
#   [2, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1]
#   [2, 0, 3, 4, 1, 1]
#   [2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 1]
#   [2, 0, 3, 5, 2, 1]
#   [2, 0, 3, 6, 2, 1]
#   [3, 0, 3, 6, 2, 1]
#   [4, 0, 3, 6, 2, 1]
#   [4, 0, 3, 6, 3, 1]
#   [4, 0, 3, 6, 4, 1]
#   [4, 1, 3, 6, 4, 1]
```